# Failed to copy Xcode project to another version of OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, compatibility

I create a project with Xcode 4.5.1 on OS X 10.8. Configurations are:
Project:
Architectures: Standard (32/64-bit intel)
Base SDK: OS X 10.7
Deployment Target: 10.7

At first everything goes smoothly.However, when I copy this project to another Macbook with Xcode 4.4.1 on OS X 10.7, runtime errors are thrown.

---

Configurations above un changed, and error occurs at a method that fetch configuration string from file:

```
+(NSString *)configValueFromFile:(NSString *)path
               withParameter:(NSString *)parameter
{
const char *cPath = [path UTF8String];
const char *cPara = [[parameter uppercaseString] UTF8String];
char buff[CFG_CONFIG_READ_TOOL_BUFFER_LEN];
size_t paraLen = [parameter length];
size_t lineLen;
FILE *fileFd = NULL;
//struct stat dummyFileStat;
BOOL isValueFound = NO;

NSString *ret = nil;

/* open file *//*
if (0 != stat(cPath, &dummyFileStat))
{
    NSLog(@"stat() %@: %@", path, [AMCTools strError]);
    return nil;
}*/


fileFd = fopen(cPath, "r");
if(!fileFd)
{
    NSLog(@"fopen() %@: %@", path, [AMCTools strError]);
    return nil;
}

/* read configuration */
while((!feof(fileFd)) && (!isValueFound))
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        size_t tmp;

        fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fileFd);
        if ('\0' == buff[sizeof(buff) - 1])
        {
            break;
        }

        /* get a line */
        lineLen = strlen(buff);
        if ((0 == lineLen) || ('#' == buff[0]))
        {
            continue;   /* !!!!!!! */
        }

        while(('\n' == buff[lineLen - 1]) ||
              ('\r' == buff[lineLen - 1]))
        {
            buff[lineLen - 1] = '\0';
            lineLen --;
        }

        //NSLog(@"Get line: %s", buff);

        /* upper case the parameter */
        for (tmp = 0;
             (tmp < lineLen) || ('=' != buff[tmp]);
             tmp++)
        {
            if ((buff[tmp] >= 'a') && (buff[tmp] <= 'z'))
            {
                buff[tmp] += 'A' - 'a';
            }
        }

        /* compare */
        if (0 == strncmp(cPara, buff, paraLen))
        {
            isValueFound = YES;

            /* fetch value sector */
            for (tmp = paraLen; tmp < lineLen; tmp++)
            {
                if ('=' == buff[tmp])
                {
                    tmp++;
                    break;
                }
            }   // end: for (tmp = paraLen...)

            if (tmp >= lineLen)
            {
                /* no parameter values */
                ret = @"";
            }
            else
            {
                /* skip blank */
                for (/**/; tmp < lineLen; tmp++)
                {
                    if ((' ' != buff[tmp]) &&
                        ('\t' != buff[tmp]))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                ret = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buff+tmp];
            }
        }   // end: compare
    }   // end: autoreleasepool
}   //end: while(...)


ENDS:
    if (fileFd)
    {
        fclose(fileFd);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This Method goes fine until the "return ret", which throws a error "**Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**";

---

What should I do?

Thanks!!

---

Further information for *Cody*:

1. About your concern:

Oh, I forgot mentioning that I did use ARC. It should had not been release.

You mentioned about the line:

```
const char *cPara = [[parameter uppercaseString] UTF8String];
```

If it is not appropriate, how should I correct it?

Comment: are you sure that if you place it in other place that method is called at all? Place some NSLog in it to see. And by the way if you are using ARC remove @autoreleasepool block - it is little bit confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I take my "latest trial" back. Maybe that is only one luck or something else. I tried comment out the autoreleasepool, and add a NSLog between "<i>fclose()</i>" and "<i>return ret</i>". It proved that "ret" still retained at the time NSLog() is. But after it return, it is released as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like your return value was released. As far as I know `stringWithUTF8String:` returns autoreleased string. And in your case it is inside `@autoreleasepool` block. And when block is end ret is released and you return some garbage.
Also I'm worrying about this line:

```
const char *cPara = [[parameter uppercaseString] UTF8String];
```

here cPara will point inside temporary string. This can be either a leak or may be a crash (with ARC).
You should store uppercase string in some intermediate variable:

```
NSString uppercaseParam = [parameter uppercaseString];
const char* cPara = [uppercaseParam UTF8String];
```

You definitely should take a look at ARC - it is very convenient feature.

Comment: I tried "return [NSString stringWithstring: ret];". But it does not work, either.

Comment: Thats not the point, with ARC you shouldn't copy return value. As for the inappropriate line: you should save uppercase string to some NSString first and only after that you can get pointer to UTF8String data because that pointer will be correct only while uppercase string exists.

Comment: Do you have stack trace, or did you try to go through your code step by step with debugger?

Comment: You should get such experience, it will be of much help in future. There are plenty of resources around the internet. It is not so hard, you just set the breakpoint, run your program, click "step over", "step over", "step over"... and than BOOM - you have your crash cause. Sorry, but I don't know what else might lead to crash here. Did you fix uppercase string line as I suggested before?

Comment: Haha, I know that experience would be a great use. I would be quite a way to master that. I will keep it in mind. The uppercase string line still remains. Any suggestions? Maybe I should use something like malloc() and free() instead.

Comment: I patch this problem temporarily using Localizable.strings as config files... Still, I haven't figured out where goes wrong.